# Adding a CSS Container In Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello could anyone please help me with my Joomla website. I need to add a CSS Container in the middle of the page but don't know how to add it. I can provide login details if you like if anyone wants to have a look for me and help me out.

Thankyou so much much appreciated.

Comment: What does the css look like?  Are you calling it with inline styles or stylesheet?  Is it going in an article, component, or a module?  Be more specific with your questions as well as what steps have you attempted?

Comment: What do you mean a CSS Container? You want to add a class or an id in a specific piece of text?

Answer (score 0):

Hi The best thing to do is to either edit an article by targeting the code editor and adding an element there e.g. `<div></div>` and then style that appropriately.

The second option would be to create a custom html module (Extensions > Module Manager) and then create a Custom HTML module. You should then chose your module position and include it on the page that you want to display the Custom HTML from your module. see [Joomla Module Positions](https://docs.joomla.org/Module_Position)

Finally if you add this directly to your active template code (which can be found under the templates folder in your main Joomla folder).